# Настройка ЧПУ для SEO url страниц фильтра товаров, для сайта на Wordpress (обычный сайт каталог без WooCommerce)

Tags: wordpress, url, seo, filter

Как в Wordpress можно реализовать механизм, чтобы GET параметры стали такими /parameter/parameter/ и.т.д.? Буду благодарен любой помощи, возможно есть плагин.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.